# No Windows Install Disc

Tags: windows-xp, reinstall, license-key

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I reinstall windows without a CD/DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/158964/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-without-a-cd-dvd)
>   [Need to reinstall Windows XP Professional - but no longer have the CD](https://superuser.com/questions/219741/need-to-reinstall-windows-xp-professional-but-no-longer-have-the-cd)

My in-laws bought a used PC that came with XP Professional. After getting a nasty virus, they re-installed Windows, but used a Home Edition disc that came with another computer they have.

They were, of course, unable to activate the new copy of Windows, since the license key was for the Professional edition. They don't have any Pro discs, and they can't use the license key that goes with the disc they used to re-install with, since it's in use on the other computer.

So what's the best option at this point? Find a download of an XP Pro disc somehow? Will it have to be an OEM Pro disc? (since the computer was most likely OEM and not retail)

Comment: Time to upgrade to 7

Comment: Ubuntu Linux is free

Comment: http://www.computersurgeons.com/Default.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I reinstall windows without a CD/DVD?](http://superuser.com/questions/158964/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-without-a-cd-dvd) and/or [Need to reinstall Windows XP Professional - but no longer have the CD](http://superuser.com/questions/219741/need-to-reinstall-windows-xp-professional-but-no-longer-have-the-cd)

Answer (score 4):

Find / download an OEM XP Pro disk. Use the license key on the computer. You are not pirating the software, you have a legal license for XP Pro on that machine. If it is a major brand - Dell, HP, etc. you may be able to buy recovery media from the manufacturer at a reasonable price.

Pretty much any local PC shop should have a collection of recovery disks for various makes.

Comment: Technically it is pirating, but is done all the time to get an OEM PC reinstalled. Microsoft does not legally allow OS install discs to be downloadable unless you have an Action Pack, MSDN subscription, or purchased from Digital River.